# Efficiently blocking invalid solutions

Tags: optaplanner

What's the best way to block invalid solutions in Optaplanner? I know you can provide a negative hard score with HardSoftScore, but it might still take a long time exploring invalid solutions before arriving at a valid one.

For example, if you're seeing how many packages will fit in a truck, if the sum size of all packages exceeds the capacity of the truck, you don't want to explore any solutions in that space at all.

Comment: Hey, would appreciate an answer or feedback instead of downvotes, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think this runs counter to the way Optaplanner is expected to work, in which you have a lot of bad solutions and slowly converge towards a good solution. Veto'ing solutions doesn't give Optaplanner any information on *why* that solution was vetoed, and also it's possible that a better solution can only be found after traversing though a vetoable solution.

Instead, consider whether your score constraints are causing a [score trap](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.44.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#scoreTrap). Instead of using a fixed -1 hard score for a vetoable solution, have a score that's proportional to how bad that solution is.

In my example, this means instead of marking overcapacity solutions as hard -1, I should instead penalize them proportional to *how* over capacity they are, using the `matchWeigher` form of `penalize`.

Comment: Relevant warning from the linked documentation: "Always specify the degree of infeasibility."